# How do I set up USB scanning with my Brother MFC-6800?

Tags: brother, scanning

I have a Brother MFC-6800 and was able to set up the printer drivers all set up via synaptic.  How do I get scanning working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html

As of Ubuntu 11.10, USB scanning is no longer supported for the MFC-6800 scanner :(